# Hide specified tag <li> from my code by JavaScript function but not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to delete or hide the button first or the second button by (function dmenubutton), but it's not working.

```js
function showitems(cell) {
  cell.querySelector(".items").style.display = "block";
}

function hideitems(cell) {
  cell.querySelector(".items").style.display = "none";
}

function showitem(cell) {
  cell.querySelector(".bottoneditmenu").style.display = "block";
}

function hideitem(cell) {
  cell.querySelector(".bottoneditmenu").style.display = "none";
}

function dmenubutton(call) {
  cell.querySelector(".bottonmenu").style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
.bottonmenu {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #b7c0cd;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Deletetbuttonmenud {
  color: #2b9ff6;
  background: #222c3c;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.Deletetbuttonmenue {
  color: #2b9ff6;
  background: #222c3c;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 1px 3px 1px 3px;
}

.Deletetbuttonmenue:hover,
.Deletetbuttonmenud:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.bottoneditmenu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="bottonmenu" onmouseover="showitem(this)" onmouseout="hideitem(this)">First botton
    <div class="bottoneditmenu">
      <span class="Deletetbuttonmenud" onclick="dmenubutton(this)">Delete</span>
      <span class="Deletetbuttonmenue">Edit</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="bottonmenu" onmouseover="showitem(this)" onmouseout="hideitem(this)">Sacand botton
    <div class="bottoneditmenu">
      <span class="Deletetbuttonmenud" onclick="dmenubutton(this)">Delete</span>
      <span class="Deletetbuttonmenue">Edit</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are clicking on span with class `Deletetbuttonmenud` and searching for element with `bottonmenu` class inside of that span.

Also you have a typo, in function you call `call` and inside `cell`

`cell.querySelector` works like this: when you click item(cell) and attach `.querySelector` on it, it searchers for term inside of that clicked element.

As seen from HTML you want to hide a `parentElement` of a `parentElement`  (`li` element with class `bottonmenu` )of that clicked span:

```
cell.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
```

```js
function showitems(cell) {
  cell.querySelector(".items").style.display = "block";
}

function hideitems(cell) {
  cell.querySelector(".items").style.display = "none";
}

function showitem(cell) {
  cell.querySelector(".bottoneditmenu").style.display = "block";
}

function hideitem(cell) {
  cell.querySelector(".bottoneditmenu").style.display = "none";
}



function dmenubutton(cell) {
  cell.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
.bottonmenu {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #b7c0cd;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Deletetbuttonmenud {
  color: #2b9ff6;
  background: #222c3c;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.Deletetbuttonmenue {
  color: #2b9ff6;
  background: #222c3c;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 1px 3px 1px 3px;
}

.Deletetbuttonmenue:hover,
.Deletetbuttonmenud:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.bottoneditmenu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="bottonmenu" onmouseover="showitem(this)" onmouseout="hideitem(this)">First botton
    <div class="bottoneditmenu">
      <span class="Deletetbuttonmenud" onclick="dmenubutton(this)">Delete</span>
      <span class="Deletetbuttonmenue">Edit</span>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="bottonmenu" onmouseover="showitem(this)" onmouseout="hideitem(this)">Sacand botton
    <div class="bottoneditmenu">
      <span class="Deletetbuttonmenud" onclick="dmenubutton(this)">Delete</span>
      <span class="Deletetbuttonmenue">Edit</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```